# data-icon attribute on android browsers

Tags: android, ios, css, navigation, responsive-design

Has anyone see some odd layout issues with a `data-icon` attribute on android mobile browsers?

I'm working on a responsive site and I'm noticing that in my test on some android phones (Droid Razr and Samsung Galaxy II) that the font icon that I'm using for my responsive menu seems to be ignoring some of the padding on the parent element.

But it appears correcly on my iPhone and on my 1st generation Droid.

Here are some screen shots:

Droid and Galaxy:

[image]

iPhone (iOS):

[image]

I'm also testing it out through Adobe edge inspect and I can't see anything within the CSS that would make it just ignore the parent elements padding.

Here's the current markup for that menu item:

HTML:

```
<a class="open" href="#menu-main-nav">Menu<span data-icon="a"></span></a>
```

CSS (SCSS to be specific):

```
.open{display: none; float: right; font: 2em $rosewood; margin-top: 30px;
     span{vertical-align: -3px;}
    @media screen and (max-width: 959px) {display: block;}
}
```

And here's the CSS for the `data-icon` attribute:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "untitled-font-1";
src:url("fonts/untitled-font-1.eot");
src:url("fonts/untitled-font-1.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("fonts/untitled-font-1.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("fonts/untitled-font-1.svg#untitled-font-1") format("svg"),
url("fonts/untitled-font-1.woff") format("woff");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

[data-icon]:before {
font-family: "untitled-font-1" !important;
content: attr(data-icon);
font-style: normal !important;
font-weight: normal !important;
font-variant: normal !important;
text-transform: none !important;
speak: none;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
font-family: "untitled-font-1" !important;
font-style: normal !important;
font-weight: normal !important;
font-variant: normal !important;
text-transform: none !important;
speak: none;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;}


.icon-align-justify:before {
content: "a";}
```

So, I'm not sure if it's just me or if it's something that I'm missing.

Comment: How does the `data-icon` attribute relate to the issue? It is not used in the styling at all.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - That's what I'm not sure about either. I updated my post to include the CSS that attributes to the font icon.
The odd thing is if I flip the icon in front of the Menu text, it overlaps. Almost if the positioning was absolute on the Android browsers.

Comment: This appears to be part of jQuery Mobile, rather than purely CSS? Perhaps you should add that tag to your question. I feel like it'd be easier to just add some right padding and a background image rather than relying on `before` stuff though.

Comment: @jblasco - Hmmm, well I'm using jQuery pageslide for the responsive menu, but I'm un-aware of any usage of jQuery mobile. Unless it's defaulting to that somehow.
I could add some extra padding, but won't that effect the over all layout to other mobile devices as well?

Comment: @ultraloveninja Well `data-icon` isn't like a native attribute that automatically does what you want- it's used by a framework you're using, or at least in this case your CSS. When I searched for `data-icon` the results are overwhelmingly jQuery Mobile-related.

Comment: @jblasco - Yeah, I noticed that as well. Hmmm. Freaking odd if you ask me. Never seen this before.